# Eclipse RCP: add external directories to classpath

Tags: eclipse, classpath, rcp

I have an eclipse RCP application, where I need to add some external jar files.
The problem is that I can't add the jars simply to a plugin and add this plugin to my RCP application.

For several reasons I must only add paths to directories where the jar files are located. These jar files have to be added to the program's classpath at startup.
And the paths to the directories are a variable (e.g. they are placed in a file).

Is there a possibility to add external paths somehow to the classpath?

Comment: Can I maybe add something to the resulting eclipise.ini s.th. I can extend the classpath?

Comment: Mmm??? Custom class loader maybe? And then you may share api interfaces to access those classes or use reflection. Also if those directories contains bundles then you may install it via Equinox framework.

Comment: If you choose OSGi way then look at `BundleContext.installBundle(location, stream)`

Answer (score 0):

add external directory to classpath,there are three method:

```
>  **1. System.setProperty("java.class.path",
> System.getProperty("java.class.path")+";"+"directory");**
```

1. File file = new File("/home/../my.jar"); 
   URLClassLoader classloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(); 
   Method add = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class }); 
   add.setAccessible(true); 
   add.invoke(classloader, new Object[] { file.toURI().toURL() });
2. configurate classpath variable in .bashrc

Comment: The first thing does not work obviously.
And the third option is rather strange.

The second thing works some kind of, but in my case I get an NoSuchMethodError when invocing the methods of the dynamically added jars.

Comment: you are right,system read the property at startup,so modify it at runtime does not work.